# SaltStack Rendering SLS 'base:tomee' failed: Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'app-server'

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to configure tomee on our dev server. Here is the sample init file.

`{% set user = pillar.x3ds.user %}
{% set tomee = pillar.tomee %}
{% set path = tomee.target_path %}
{% set service = tomee.service %}`

target_path and service are saved in pillar files as seen below.

```
tomee:
service: app-server
target_path: /u01/tomee
version: 1_7_4
startup: startup
ports:
    shutdown: 8005
    http: 8080
    ajp: 8009
    jmx: 9099
```

I am able to retreive target_path but getting error as below for service.

### Data failed to compile:

```
Rendering SLS 'base:tomee' failed: Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'app-server'
```

I am very new to saltstack and searched on google for quite sometime now. I am sure I am missing very basic thing but not able to get eactly. Your help would be appreciated.

I also tried set service diredctly in my init file but still see same error there also.

Answer (score 1):

Root cause for error in my case was somewhere below in my init file. I was using service attribute to read a complex dict object I guess.

{- repl: Connector port="{{ site_index[service].http }}" protocol="HTTP/1.1"\1}